# Browser picking wrong version of hammerjs

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I have an angular application where inside package.json file I see hammerjs version as 2.0.8. Inside package-lock.json file also I see the same version info as 2.0.8 only. When I execute the command 'npm list hammerjs', there also I see the hammerjs version as 2.0.8. But when I render my application in browser, then inside browser developer tools inside 'Sources' tab when I open hammerjs file, there I see the version as 2.0.7. Also when I use the 'Wappalyzer' chrome extension to check for hammerjs version, it shows version as 2.0.7 only. I am not getting from where the version of 2.0.7 is getting picked. Kindly help!!

Package.json file looks like below: -

```html
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "14.0.0-beta.41",
    "@angular/forms": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/localize": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "14.2.10",
    "@ng-idle/core": "9.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "9.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "5.9.3",
    "@ngx-formly/material": "5.9.3",
    "@reachplatform/core": "2.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.12",
    "amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk": "^1.18.1",
    "angular2-moment": "1.9.0",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "concurrently": "5.3.0",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "d3": "^7.3.0",
    "deprecated-decorator": "0.1.6",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "express": "4.17.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "helmet": "4.1.0",
    "html2canvas": "1.0.0-rc.5",
    "jspdf": "2.3.1",
    "mime": "2.4.6",
    "morgan": "1.10.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "5.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "10.0.1",
    "ngx-mask": "9.1.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "5.0.0",
    "ngx-trim-directive": "1.0.11",
    "nocache": "2.1.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "0.0.1-alpha.32",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "14.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.2.10",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@types/d3": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint": "^7.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^39.6.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "jest": "^28.0.8",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^12.2.3",
    "jest-sonar": "0.2.11",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "ts-node": "9.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is inside node_modules folder we have a hammerjs folder. Inside this when I check package.json file, it shows me a version 2.0.8 but when I open the hammer.js file (this is also present inside hammerjs folder) there I see the version as 2.0.7. This is the same file that gets loaded in browser when I search for it inside 'Sources' tab. How to update this hammer.js file to the version 2.0.8?

Comment: Have you tried to delete node_modules and webpack cache and installing it again?